# Api returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: jquery, json, api

I have an Api server and it works almost perfect. When my website calls the Api-server and ask for "action" below, it throw an error if it returns 0 mails*

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public newMessageList GetMessagesbyUser(string userid)
{
    List<MessageList> m = new List<MessageList>();
    List<Messages> s = db.Messages.Include(i => i.ToUser).Include(i => i.FromUser).Where(i => i.ToUser.Id.ToString() == userid).ToList();
    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        m.Add(new MessageList() { Date = item.DateCreated, From = item.FromUser.Username, To = item.ToUser.Username, Message = item.Text, Subject = item.Subject, Key = item.ID.ToString(), FromFirstName = item.FromUser.FirstName, FromLastName = item.FromUser.LastName });
    }

    return new newMessageList() { Count = GetUnreadMessages(s.First().ToUser), MessageList = m };
}
```

AllowCrossSiteJson attribute:

```
public class AllowCrossSiteJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

If `GetMessageByUser` returns 0 in MessageList It returns the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:56905/api/Get/GetMessagesbyUser/?userid=b852e7d4-d663-41d9-8db5-0b253df7c194. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54623' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

But if it returns 1 or more in MessageList it works perfect and runs without throwing an error.

Do anyone have an idea how to fix this? I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
return new newMessageList() { Count = GetUnreadMessages(s.First().ToUser), MessageList = m };
```

you are accessing `s.First()` unconditionally. Of course it throws exception if the list is empty.